# Sending notification when a new site created SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can I get any suggestion on sending email to a SharePoint group when a site is created on SharePoint Online out of box.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, there is no OOTB method to achieve this requirement.

There is no site created trigger action in flow and for SharePoint add-in, there is no site-level trigger event.